# GetServerData in template ( Gatsby retrieving data problems)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, server-side-rendering

I wanted to ask about gatsby and graphql as I'm having trouble retrieving the necessary data:

1- is it possible to insert getServerData inside a template in case of dynamically created pages? From Gatsby's documentation I only find getServerData related documentation only within pages that stay at src/pages. I'm trying to pass a variable to getServerData via the createPages context in gatsby-node.

Alternatively:

2- Using the dynamic creation of pages via File System Routing, in this case [...slug] I would like to pass the slug variable to a page query, in order to be able to filter a query of the type allCms.

```
query CollectionPageQuery($slug: String) {    
    allCmsPlp(
      filter: { parameters: { collection: { seo: { slug: { eq: $slug } } } } }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          parameters {
            collection {
              seo {
                slug
              }
              brandId
              categoryId
              generic
              clusterId
            }
          }
          sections {
            name
            data
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

In the first case the getServerData does not work for me, in the second case I encountered build problems and it tells me that the slug variable does not exist and for this reason I assume it is not passed.

What do you recommend in the situation if I want to have:

- pages created dynamically
- page query that takes a variable
- getServerData with SSR query

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it possible to insert getServerData inside a template in case of dynamically created pages.
2. Whatever you pass as a context in gatsby-node.js will appear as props.pageContext inside getServerData.

   export async function getServerData(props) { console.log(props.pageContext) }

Answer (score 0):

Create the pages dynamically in your gatsby-node file, e.g.: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/#createPages

When you create the pages, you pass a context. Put your variable (objectId, slug etc.) into this context.

On the template side, that context will now be available in getServerData as { pageContext }.

You can pull your variable from that context, use it to retrieve your page data, then return it from getServerData as "props".

Your page data will then be available as {serverData} in your main page component.